# python MySQLdb: SELECT DISTINCT - why returning long

Tags: python, long-integer, mysql-python

Here's a shortened version of my script:

```
import MySQLdb
src_db = MySQLdb.connect(**some_connection)
src_cursor = src_db.cursor()
v = src_cursor.execute('SELECT node_id FROM stats WHERE time_unit >= 1388534400')
```

`v` ends up being of `long` type, which I cannot understand. I expect to have a generator that would return 1-element tuples (I ask only for one column). And it returns a long value, being number of rows returned from db. Why?

When I try to iterate through it:

```
node_ids = {int(x[0]) for x in v}
```

I get following error:

```
TypeError: 'long' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the [python database API specification, PEP-249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).

Basically, after you've executed a query with a cursor object, you then query the cursor object for the results.

```
cursor.execute(my_sql)

for record in cursor.fetchall():
    # do stuff
```

Comment: this answer provides link to an important resource - accepted

Answer (score 2):

`src_cursor.execute(SELECT_QUERY)` will return the number of rows matching your query.

To iterate through the result of the query:

`for row in src_cursor.fetchall():`

To get one row at a time:

`row = src_cursor.fetchone()`